# Is there a way to enable the button only if all 5 boxes are checked?

Tags: button, checkbox

Currently you only need one checkbox to be checked in order to activate the button. I would like to make it so 3 of the checkmarks need to be checked in order to activate.

http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/BPhZe/76/

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear -- do you want all five (as claimed in the title) or three (as claimed in the text) boxes to be checked?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! The issue is you should use the ":not()" selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/douglasloyo/BPhZe/470/

```
    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
        submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

    checkboxes.click(function() {
        submitButt.attr("disabled", checkboxes.is(":not(:checked")));
    });
```

Comment: You bet! Please don't forget to mark my response as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many checkboxes are set using:

```
var numChecked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9whF5/ Change the condition if you want at least three boxes to be checked. As is, the fiddle requires exactly three boxes to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. It even disables if the third is unchecked.

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BPhZe/471/

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    if ($(":checkbox:checked").length >= 3){
    submitButt.attr("disabled", false);
    }
    else{
    submitButt.attr("disabled", true);
    }

});
```